# Made a .jar file of an app I made using JFrame in java. Which works 100%. But when I have it loading from a website, its just a blank white screen

Tags: java, deployment, jar, applet, jframe

So as I tried to describe in the title.

I made an application that works 100% when compiled, and also when opened with the .jar file I made for it.

So my next step was to run this from my online portfolio. However, when I use the

```
    <APPLET ARCHIVE="xxxxx.jar" CODE="xxxxx.class" WIDTH=400 HEIGHT=300>
    </APPLET>
```

approach... So the Applet prompts me to run, I click Yes. My JFrame pops up like it normally would, however it is just a completely white blank screen. ( no content from my app )

I must have them linked appropriately if the JFrame even loads at all. So I'm not sure whats up.

Any help? Thanks

Edit: I forgot to mention, I am running this locally at the moment. Not sure if they would have anything to do with anything.

Comment: Have you tried enabling the Java console for debugging?

Comment: `JFrame` != `JApplet`, applets should not be creating frames and may actually be blocked from doing so if the secutiry restrictions are strong enough

Comment: Ok. Understood. Thank you! Question then: What method would I use to upload a .jar file to be executed from a web page? If any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What method would I use to upload a .jar file to be executed from a web page?

For deploying Java desktop apps., the best option is usually to install the app. using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS works on Windows, OS X & *nix.